# Why doesn't Gauss Divergence Theorem work for me?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I need to evaluate the volume $$V=\{(x,y,z) \mid 0≤x≤2,\; 0≤y≤2,\; \frac x2\leq z\leq-x+3\}$$

The sum of the double integrals gives me a value of $12$
And the triple integral gives me a value of $24$
What am I doing wrong? Can someone please point out my mistake?

Comment: Can you write down the integrals? I'm sure it's just a small mistake

Comment: A very small one, I fixed it already. BTW, I just created an account here and I don't know how to write down integrals, or anything in math language for that matter.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\iiint_V1dzdydx=2\int_0^2\int_{x/2}^{3-x}1dzdx$$$$=6\int_0^21-\frac x2dx$$$$=6\bigg(x-\frac{x^2}4\bigg)\bigg|_0^2$$$$=12$$